# Limit the access of application

Tags: iphone, ios, iphone-sdk-3.0

I want to create an application that does some tasks in mail account.
The user will link his mail account to the application.
The question is: is it possible to restrict the access for specific user's account only from his phone (the phone that the application installed and registed on )?

Comment: For example: if i installed this application on my iphone and linked her to mail acount - XXXX  than the access to this app with acount XXXX will be only from my ipone and impossible from any other phone

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit confusing. It sounds like you might be looking for Keychain services: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html

Basically, your app would store credentials and other sensitive info in the keychain. Once in there, that data is encrypted and only accessed by your app.